# How to properly dispose objects in Flambe?

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, dispose, haxe, flambe

In [this Flambe guide](https://github.com/markknol/flambe-guide/wiki/Components#boom-destruction) it says:

*"This dispose function removes this component from its owning entity. You should override the dispose-function in order to dispose objects yourself, to prevent memory leaks."*

I have 3 questions:

1. How should I override the dispose function?
2. How to properly use the dispose function?
3. Is there a way to check for memory leaks in Flambe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 If you're using `Component`

```
 override public function dispose() {
   myReferences = null;
   myDisposable.dispose();

   super.dispose();
 }
```

If you are not using a `Component`: 
You can implement `Disposable` and dispose when needed in another dispose function.

2 You need to clear references to objects, that means set it to null.
   You need to close signal connections that are created in that context.
   You need to dispose the `Disposable`s.

3 If you use the JavaScript (html) target, you can use the chrome debug inspector / devtools. You can collect memory profiles, observe the cpu usage etc. Really useful! https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/profiles

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just a few questions:

When you wrote `myReferences` you meant references to this component object, right?

What is `myDisposable`?

We call `super.dispose()` in order to remove this component from its owner, right?

Comment: myDisposable is anything used in your component that is implementing `Disposable` interface. myReference was another example for objects used in your component which are not implementing `Disposable`.

Comment: And yes, you should always do `super.dispose()`, because this removes the component from its owner.

Comment: For convenience you can also use a `Disposer`  in your component, add any `Disposable` to it (like signals etc) and do `myDisposer.dispose()` when you override the dispose function.

Comment: https://github.com/markknol/flambe-guide/wiki/Signal-Event-System#boom-dispose-signals